# Handling ajax requests, not receiving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

i'm having a hard time setting up my client-side ajax calls to send data to node express server.
i want to fire my ajax request "onclick" of an href link.

I'm trying to send the ID of the link as a variable to the server, but the server doesn't receive my data (without setInterval)

if i put the ajax request inside a `setInterval()` (which i don't want to do, because i only want to send the data once a link is clicked to the server),
the server receives the data in `res.req.body`, why?

**client side:**

```
 $('.link_group').click(function () { 
    data = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajax_handler",
      data: {id: data}
    });
 });
```

**server side**

```
app.post("/ajax_handler", function(req, res) {
  res.send({  //works as it should....
    user       : req.session.user,
    data_objekt: req.session.data
  });

  if(res.req.body) {
    console.log(res.req.body);
  }
});
```

Is this even a common way to "catch" the data from client?

`if(res.req.body) {...`

doesn't seems right, but i don't know how to do it in a smarter way / can't find any good examples. 
I'm about to fire 3-4 Ajax other requests to `/ajax_handler` which leads to my next question: how to handle multiple ajax requests to the same url?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: might be because you are trying to do stuff with the res obj after you send the response back (res should be closed). try moving the `res.send()` to the end of app.post callback.

Comment: The data the user is sending to you is inside `req.body`

Comment: I believe it should req.body and not res.req.body

Comment: req.body is {}

just like res.req.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you parsing the request? req.body is initially empty/undefined. You will need to pass it to a middleware that parses the data into req.body. Body-parser is a nodejs module that can achieve this. Here's how to a POST request with JSON data being sent.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/ajax_handler", function(req, res) {
   res.send({  //works as it should....
     user       : req.session.user,
     data_objekt: req.session.data
   });
  if(req.body) {
    console.log(req.body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the content-type? I'm not sure what data you are sending but the docs say that contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')